# Hover over an item in the dropdown list in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to hover over an item in the dropdown list in selenium webdriver? I knew about clicking, however I need to moverOver on each and every item and check the url is a secured one.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to mouse over an item and check the url?

Comment: Please add some HTML Snippet of the webpage

Answer (score 0):

You can hover you mouse on dropdown item but you can verify its url!

You can verify it by look at htlm code. For exmple:

```
<ul id="dropdown">
    <li id="item001" class="">
        <a href="link1.html" title="Link 1">Link 1</a> 
    </li>
    <li id="item002" class="">
        <a href="link2.html" title="Link 2">Link 2</a>    
    </li>

</ul>
```

In the html code above, I have a dropdown list with 2 items List 1 and List 2.

If you want to verify what link is in each item, you should get link from item (attribute href) and compare it to expected result.
Or even if you want verify title just get title attribute.

Hope useful.

Answer (score 0):

When using Java, for example:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example how we could implement this.

[image]

```
public class HoverableDropdownTest {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private Actions action;

    Consumer < By > hover = (By by) - > {
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(by))
              .perform();
    };

    @Test
    public void hoverTest() {
        driver.get("https://www.bootply.com/render/6FC76YQ4Nh");

        hover.accept(By.linkText("Dropdown"));
        hover.accept(By.linkText("Dropdown Link 5"));
        hover.accept(By.linkText("Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4"));
        hover.accept(By.linkText("Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.1"));
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void setupDriver() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        action = new Actions(driver);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void teardownDriver() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

For detailed answer, check here - http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automating-hoverable-multilevel-dropdowns/